# Updating Database And Query Based On Location

Tags: php, android, jquery, mysql, location

For the last few days I've been trying to fix up the code in Android so that I can OnLocationChanged () send the new Latitude and Longitude to the database and also when it's updated I want it to query based on location. However I'm having a trouble doing it android and I was wondering if there is a way to "combine" the two php codes I use for Updating and Querying the database. Both codes work separately, but can I be combined?
I need the database to be Updated with the new data and then query or vice versa.

Update.php

```
$latitude1 = $_POST["Latitude"];
$longitude1 = $_POST["Longitude"];
$username = $_POST["Username"];

$updatequery = mysqli_prepare($con , "UPDATE users SET Latitude = ?, Longitude = ? WHERE Username = ?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($updatequery ,"dds",$latitude1,$longitude1,$username);
mysqli_stmt_execute($updatequery);
 mysqli_stmt_close($updatequery);
mysqli_close($con);
```

QueryByLocation.php

```
$origLat = $_POST["Latitude"];
$origLon = $_POST["Longitude"];
$dist = 30;
$id = $_POST["ID"];

if(mysqli_connect_errno($con)) {
die("Connection failed : " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "SELECT ID, Name, Age, City, Gender, Latitude, Longitude, 3956 * 2 * 1.609344 * 1000 *
          ASIN(SQRT( POWER(SIN(($origLat - abs(Latitude))*pi()/180/2),2)
          +COS($origLat*pi()/180 )*COS(abs(Latitude)*pi()/180)
          *POWER(SIN(($origLon-Longitude)*pi()/180/2),2))) 
          as distance FROM users WHERE ID != '$id'
          AND Longitude BETWEEN ($origLon-$dist/abs(cos(radians($origLat))*69)) 
          AND ($origLon+$dist/abs(cos(radians($origLat))*69)) 
          AND Latitude BETWEEN ($origLat-($dist/69)) 
          AND ($origLat+($dist/69))
          HAVING distance < $dist ORDER BY distance limit 30;"; 



$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

$rows = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $rows[] = $row;
}

mysqli_close($con);
echo json_encode($rows);
```

Comment: "I need the database to be Updated with the new data and then query or vice versa." You need both the cases if yes then do you have any criteria when you need to query db first and then update the lat long or first update lat long then query to db?

Comment: It doesn't matter if the db is updated with the lat and long first and then the query is executed (so it can be either way). But I guess It would be smarter to do it like UPDATE then QUERY.

Comment: you want a combined code for both?

Comment: Yes, do you know how?

Comment: Are the lat long will be same for both QueryByLocation.php and Update.php?

Comment: Yes, that's also why combining them would be really useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$origLat = $_POST["Latitude"];
$origLon = $_POST["Longitude"];
$dist = 30;
$id = $_POST["ID"];
$username = $_POST["Username"];
if(mysqli_connect_errno($con)) {
die("Connection failed : " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$updatequery = mysqli_prepare($con , "UPDATE users SET Latitude = ?, Longitude = ? WHERE Username = ?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($updatequery ,"dds",$origLat,$origLon,$username);
mysqli_stmt_execute($updatequery);
 mysqli_stmt_close($updatequery);

$sql = "SELECT ID, Name, Age, City, Gender, Latitude, Longitude, 3956 * 2 * 1.609344 * 1000 *
          ASIN(SQRT( POWER(SIN(($origLat - abs(Latitude))*pi()/180/2),2)
          +COS($origLat*pi()/180 )*COS(abs(Latitude)*pi()/180)
          *POWER(SIN(($origLon-Longitude)*pi()/180/2),2))) 
          as distance FROM users WHERE ID != '$id'
          AND Longitude BETWEEN ($origLon-$dist/abs(cos(radians($origLat))*69)) 
          AND ($origLon+$dist/abs(cos(radians($origLat))*69)) 
          AND Latitude BETWEEN ($origLat-($dist/69)) 
          AND ($origLat+($dist/69))
          HAVING distance < $dist ORDER BY distance limit 30;"; 



$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

$rows = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $rows[] = $row;
}

mysqli_close($con);
echo json_encode($rows);
```